# Problems with Ampersand

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch using the current location to make some changes the problem is that this place may have the & and thus cause errors ... I wonder if there is a way to make a script that checks for the & in the variable and if you add has the ^&.

the way I am using this might be.

```
Set "Local_Script=%~dp0">nul 2>&1
Echo %Local_Script%> a00_Local.ini
```

Note: The txt file can only be with the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping characters is fine when your code is supplying a string literal. But it is often impractical when dealing with existing strings contained within variables.

There are simpler solutions:

**1) delayed expansion:**

Note that you must assign batch arguments and/or FOR variables to environment variables prior to enabling delayed expansion. Otherwise values containing `!` will be corrupted.

```
@echo off
set "local_script=%~dp0"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !local_script!>a00_local.ini
```

**2) transfer the quoted value to a simple FOR variable, then use the `~` modifier to safely remove the quotes:**

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("%~dp0") do echo %%~F>a00_local.ini
```

**3) transfer the quoted string value to a FOR /F variable, which automatically removes the quotes:**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ("%~dp0") do eho %%F>a00_local.ini
```